# Get account information from people that purchased app

Tags: android, google-play, account

I have a couple apps that the US Army pulled down from Google Play for trademark infringement (I used the words US Army in the description). I have since corrected the problems, but they wont release Google to put my apps back up because they released their own version of my app and apparently dont want the competition. My apps had been out for a couple years and I have over 20k paid users. I have since released a new version of my app (different package name) and its doing ok. The problem is I cannot get updates to my old users. I dont like the idea of telling all 20k of them that in order to get the new features of the app they would have to purchase again. So, what I would like to do is create a free version of the app that would somehow query the play store to see if their play account has purchased the old version of my app. I have looked on Google and cant seem to find an answer to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I believe I'm facing the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100035/restore-transactions-of-in-app-purchases-in-another-app

Comment: I never implemented it, but there is a way and i'll find the documentation and post it on your question