# Restore transactions of in-app purchases in another app

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Using [In-App Billing v3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) and the `IabHelper` class provided by Google. Using its `queryInventoryAsync` method, it's easy to restore the user's transactions of my app. Now comes the tricky part! I need to restore transactions of *another* app of mine. Can that be done?

- Both apps have been signed with the same key.
- Both apps are published under the same developer account.
- Both apps happen to have the same [sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) (and I hope to keep it that way).

I know the use of `sharedUserId` can cause [problems](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=90) with `IAB v3` but for this particular task I believe it should be possible to get it working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**The motivation** for this feature is simple. Any in-app purchases made in my *Basic* app should be made available in my *Pro* app, without forcing the user to buy the equivalent items anew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done.
iABHelper provides information based on your package name id which gets automatically passed from your app. 
Since your other application has different package name those purchases are not going to return at all.
All you can do is to send broadcast from one app to another and process that request in other application and send that information back in first app.

Comment: Thanks. What if the source code of `IabHelper` is modified to use an arbitrary package name?